# how to do this with javascript? it's like a toggle but I don't seem to find toggle function

Tags: javascript, image, toggle, border

I'm trying to do this with javascript instead of jquery.
I want to click on a picture then the picture will have borders but if I click on it again then the border will be gone.  don't have much idea how it's done anyone can give me a hand?

```
allImages = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

    for(i=0;i<allImages.length;i++)
{
    allImages[i].onclick=function()
    {
    this.style.borderColor="red";
    this.style.borderStyle="solid";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML? Can we see your current code? Which DOM methods specifically are you looking for?

Comment: I haven't got anything yet because can't seem to get an idea in my head yet but I'm using dom1 instead of dom0.  I know the onclick funtion but it won't toggle though.

Comment: @user1850712 can we see ur code ?

Comment: this is only what I can think of now but ya....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for toggle a image with id try this code

```
var img = document.getElementById('image-id');

if( ! img.hasBorder ) {

     img.style.border="2px solid #f00";
     img.hasBorder = true;

} else {

     img.style.border = "";
     img.hasBorder = false;

}
```

---

Updated code

```
allImages = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(i=0; i< allImages.length; i++ )
{
    allImages[i].onclick = function( e )
    {
           this.style.border = ( this.style.border == '')? "2px solid red":'';
    }
}
```

Comment: do you think you can explain to me what the function e means

Comment: and how
= ( this.style.border == '')? "2px solid red":'';
works

Comment: @user1850712 e is event object .. for more details check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event

Comment: @user1850712 and for border properties check this, http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/box.html#propdef-border

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create two classes one having border and second having border none.

Now when event fire check if first class is applly then remove it and apply second class.

**Example**

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");
var testClass = test.className;

testClass = ( testClass == "first") ? "second" : "first";
```

Comment: in one line `testClass = ( testClass == "first") ? "second" : "first";`

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
document.getElementById('id').style.border
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

**// showing**

```
document.getElementById('element').style.border = 'red';
```

**// hiding**

```
document.getElementById('element').style.border = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = document.getElementById('image-id');
img.style.border = img.style.border ? "" : "2px solid red";
```